# Automatic DNS A record pointing to backup IP when main IP is down

Tags: domain-name-system, monitoring

I have a website which I monitor for downtime through Host Tracker. I have setup a backup server as well to point the A record of the main website to the backup server in case of any downtime.

These two servers are from 2 different providers so if one goes down I can quickly act and point the A record to another provider.

The problem is what if this happens over the weekend or midnight. Is there anyway to do this automatically?

This site does not have any email, MX record is just the A record.

Comment: That setup works great for scheduled downtime, but not great for unexpected outages.  Don't make the mistake of adding multiple A records - this often results in round robin DNS results, which is ok for load balancing static sites, but will not provide resilience!  For MX records however, multiple records pointing at multiple mail servers do give resilience.

Answer (score 2):

Some of the better featured DNS providers offer this as a service.  [EasyDNS](http://www.easydns.com) is one such company -- their 'Pro' service is something silly like $55/year and provides many features in addition to what they call *Failover DNS*.  You will need to transfer the management of the domain to their nameservers, though.

More details can be found [here](http://helpwiki.easydns.com/index.php/Host_Monitoring_and_Failover).

*(disclaimer: not affiliated with them; have found their Secondary DNS service to be useful, but never tried their Failover DNS)*

Answer (score 0):

A load balancer can do this. Google `global load balancer`. One or both of your hosting companies may offer this as a service.